# In CREATE FUNCTION, validate if parameters value exist in SQL then applied condition if not exist show all values

Tags: sql, function, if-statement, parameters, exists

I don't know why my SQL code doesn't work. I'm looking for a way to apply a condition on the year asked, but if it doesn't exist, it should show all year. How ever, the code its not working.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SALES_YEAR(@year int=0) RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader where 
Year(OrderDate)=@year)
SELECT Year(OrderDate) as 
[YEAR],SOH.TerritoryId,convert(varchar,SUM(SOH.SubTotal),1)as VenteTotal from AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
    GROUP BY Year(OrderDate),SOH.TerritoryID;

ELSE
    SELECT Year(OrderDate) as [year],SOH.TerritoryId,convert(varchar,SUM(SOH.SubTotal),1)+'$'as VenteTotal from AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
    Where Year(OrderDate)=@year or @year=0
    GROUP BY Year(OrderDate),SOH.TerritoryID

END)
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the table and put the results in it.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SALES_YEAR
    (
        @year INT = 0
    )
RETURNS @table TABLE
    (
        OrdYear INT ,
        TerritoryID INT ,
        VenteTotal MONEY
    )
AS
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS (   SELECT 1
                      FROM   AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader
                      WHERE  YEAR(OrderDate) = @year
                  )
            INSERT INTO @table 
            SELECT   YEAR(OrderDate) AS [YEAR] ,
                     SOH.TerritoryId ,
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(SOH.SubTotal), 1) AS VenteTotal
            FROM     AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
            GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate) ,
                     SOH.TerritoryID

        ELSE
            INSERT INTO @table
            SELECT   YEAR(OrderDate) AS [year] ,
                     SOH.TerritoryId ,
                     CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(SOH.SubTotal), 1) + '$' AS VenteTotal
            FROM     AdventureWorks2014.Sales.SalesOrderHeader SOH
            WHERE    YEAR(OrderDate) = @year
                     OR @year = 0
            GROUP BY YEAR(OrderDate) ,
                     SOH.TerritoryID;

        RETURN

    END
```